# syntax highlight regex not matching

Tags: syntax-highlighting, regular-expression, filetype

I am writing a plugin where a certain filetype must possess their own syntax highlight. Therefore I have created

```
.
├── ...
├── plugin
└── syntax
```

and `syntax/newfiletype.vim` containing

```
syntax clear
syntax match MyPattern /regexpattern/
highlight default link MyPattern Title
```

where `regexpattern` is a *valid* regex pattern that matches, say, vim search or vim regex functions, but that however does not work when having to match for syntax highlight. In the particular case at hand I want to highlight all lines containing dashes at the start of the line, therefore `/^--.*/`. The same happens if instead of the `-` one uses *any* other non-alphanumerical character.

Problem: regex pattern `^--` (or any similar one) does not work for the filetype in question when for syntax highlight.

Similar questions: [here](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23186/regex-missing-matching-words), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11788124/vim-syntax-highlighting-regular-expression) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16197749/vim-highlight-regex).

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Please [edit] to include sample text, what you expect to be matched, and what is actually matched. (Getting the syntax groups under the cursor can be helpful; plenty of tricks around this site or the internet at large for that.) Also, make sure `verbose set filetype?` shows what you expect—if the filetype is new, I would expect to see an ftdetect (and possibly ftplugin instead of/in addition to plugin) directory.